# OverflowError: size does not fit in an int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure-machine-learning-service

I am writing a python script to use in AzureML. My dataset is quite big. I have a dataset with columns called ID(int) and DataType(text). I would like to concatenate these values to just have one column with text that has both the ID and the DataType seperated by a comma.

How can I avoid getting an error when I do this. Do I have any mistakes in my code?

When i run this code I get the following error:

```
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
data:text/plain,Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 167, in batch
idfs.append(rutils.RUtils.RFileToDataFrame(infile))
File "C:\server\RReader\rutils.py", line 15, in RFileToDataFrame
rreader = RReaderFactory.construct_from_file(filename, compressed)
File "C:\server\RReader\rreaderfactory.py", line 25, in construct_from_file
return _RReaderFactory.construct_from_stream(stream)
File "C:\server\RReader\rreaderfactory.py", line 46, in construct_from_stream
return RReader(BinaryReader(RFactoryConstants.big_endian, stream.read()))
File "C:\pyhome\lib\gzip.py", line 254, in read
self._read(readsize)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\gzip.py", line 313, in _read
self._add_read_data( uncompress )
File "C:\pyhome\lib\gzip.py", line 329, in _add_read_data
self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffffL
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

My code is as below:

```
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.
#
# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame

def azureml_main(dataframe1):
import pandas as pd
dataframe1['SignalID,DataType'] = dataframe1['ID'] + " , " + dataframe1['DataType']
dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop('DataType')
dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop('ID')
# Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
return dataframe1
```

I get the same error when I run the default python code in AzureML. So I am pretty sure my data just does not fit in the data frame.

The default script is the following:

```
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.
#
# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    # Execution logic goes here
    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))

    # If a zip file is connected to the third input port is connected,
    # it is unzipped under ".\Script Bundle". This directory is added
    # to sys.path. Therefore, if your zip file contains a Python file
    # mymodule.py you can import it using:
    # import mymodule

    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return dataframe1,
```

Comment: I think you need `dataframe1['SignalID,DataType'] = dataframe1['ID'].astype(str) + " , " + dataframe1['DataType']` for converting column id to `string` and `dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop(['DataType', 'ID'], axis=1)` for droping columns `DataType` and `ID`

Answer (score 1):

If you need concatenate integer `ID` and string `DataType` columns to new column `SignalID`, use casting by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html). Then you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns `DataType` and `ID` adding parameter `axis=1`:

```
import pandas as pd

def azureml_main(dataframe1):
    dataframe1['SignalID'] = dataframe1['ID'].astype(str) 
                                      + " , " 
                                      + dataframe1['DataType']

    dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop(['DataType', 'ID'], axis=1)
    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return dataframe1
```

Comment: I get the same problem with your code. Could it be because my data does not fit in the dataframe?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. You can add example of dataframe - `print dataframe1.head()`

Comment: Or maybe is problem with creating dataframe... How you crete dataframe? With `read_csv`?

Comment: As I am using this as a script I azure machine learning it creates the dataframe for me.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe help [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163363%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)